# Create dynamic menu and submenu then this error given it

Tags: c#

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
string sql = "Select * from MenuControl";
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, con);
da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentId=" + 0))
{
    if (dr["MenuName"] != null && dr["MenuId"] != null && dr["LocationUrl"] != null)
    {
        menuBar.Items.Add(new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuId"].ToString(), "", dr["LocationUrl"].ToString()));
    }

}
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Select("ParentId>" + 0))
{
    if (dr["MenuName"] != null && dr["MenuId"] != null && dr["LocationUrl"] != null)
    {
        MenuItem mnu = new MenuItem(dr["MenuName"].ToString(), dr["MenuId"].ToString(), "", dr["LocationUrl"].ToString());


        if (dr["ParentId"] != null)
        {
            menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentId"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the error:

```
    System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
if (dr["ParentId"] != null)
Line 56:                 {
Line 57:                     menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentId"].ToString()).ChildItems.Add(mnu);
Line 58:                 }
Line 59:             }
```

Comment: There is no menuitem with valuePath `dr["ParentId"]`, if that's expected add a `null` check as Damith shows. Othwerwise fix the reason why there's no such item.

Answer (score 0):

if `FindItem`  return null? add null check before set the child items

```
var item = menuBar.FindItem(dr["ParentId"].ToString());
if(item !=null)
  item.ChildItems.Add(mnu);
```

you may need to look for the documentation for the `FindItem` of the control which using in your application, as per [Menu.FindItem](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.menu.finditem.aspx) method  you need to give value path like `"rootname,child1,child11"` but that depend on the application type you working  and the control you using.